# Haskell movies search

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell and i have a project which need to give True if conditions is meet in the list, i'm already make the other function which check if the score is above or the director is the same but now i need to merge this conditions together but i'm stuck and dont know how to do that.

The fuction need to give back true for that test cases:

```
search (director "Christopher Nolan") movies == [("Inception", 8.8, "Christopher Nolan"), ("The Dark Knight", 9.0, "Christopher Nolan")]

search (imdbAtLeast 8.2) movies == [("Green Book", 8.3, "Peter Farrelly"), ("Inception", 8.8, "Christopher Nolan"), ("The Dark Knight", 9.0, "Christopher Nolan")]

search (and_ (director "Christopher Nolan") (imdbAtLeast 8.9)) movies == [("The Dark Knight", 9.0, "Christopher Nolan")]

search (or_ (imdbAtLeast 7.5) (director "Rian Johnson")) [("The Last Jedi", 7.2, "Rian Johnson"), ("Sicario", 7.6, "Denis Villeneuve")] == [("The Last Jedi", 7.2, "Rian Johnson"), ("Sicario", 7.6, "Denis Villeneuve")]

search (\_ -> True) [] == []

search (\_ -> False) movies == []
```

my code untill that part:

```
type Movie = (String, Double, String)

-- movies :: [(String, Double, String)]
movies :: [Movie]
movies = [ ("Green Book", 8.3, "Peter Farrelly")
         , ("Inception", 8.8, "Christopher Nolan")
         , ("Incredibles 2", 7.7, "Brad Bird")
         , ("The Dark Knight", 9.0, "Christopher Nolan")
         ] 
imdbAtLeast :: Double -> (String,Double,String) -> Bool 
imdbAtLeast pointgive (_, point, _) =  point >= pointgive

director  :: String  -> (String,Double,String) -> Bool 
director  directorgive  (_, _, director) =  director == directorgive

and_ :: (Movie -> Bool) -> (Movie -> Bool) -> Movie -> Bool
and_ p q m = p m && q m

or_ :: (Movie -> Bool) -> (Movie -> Bool) -> Movie -> Bool
or_ p q m = p m || q m
```

Comment: What do you think the type of the `search` function should be?

Comment: I think its should be search :: (Movie -> Bool) -> [Movie] -> [Movie]

Comment: Ok great, can you edit your question to try to write a little bit about what you’ve tried and why it didn’t work. Or maybe if you have some ideas about how the solution might work. Or perhaps you just don’t know where to start and want some hints?

Comment: im actually dont really know how to start i dont really understand how can i go through in the maded movies list and search it by the criteria director and return the value, i tried the look at the lookup fuction.

Comment: It sounds like you need [filter](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so it seems you’re on the right track. You have an idea for the type of the search function so let’s write that down:

```
search :: (Movie -> Bool) -> [Movie] -> [Movie]
```

Let’s try to figure this out from first principles.

The first argument is a function. Let’s call it `p` for *predicate*. There isn’t much we can do with this function. The most obvious thing would be to apply it to a movie but so far we haven’t got any.

The second argument is a list of movies. Let’s pattern match on it. The first case is `[]`:

```
search p [] = (??)
```

Well we need to return a list of movies here and I don’t think we should make one up out of thin air so we should probably return none. Indeed if you search a list of no movies, surely all you can get is nothing. We don’t use the predicate argument in this case so let’s write `_` instead you make it obvious that we don’t use it:

```
search _ [] = []
```

The other case is the head of a list and the rest. Let’s call the head `m` for *movie* and following convention the tail will be called `ms`:

```
search p (m:ms) = (??)
```

At this point we now have a movie to call our function `p` with so let’s do that and consider the result:

```
search p (m:ms) =
    if p m
    then (??)
    else (??)
```

Well what do we do here? If `p m` is true then we should include `m` in the output and if it is false then we shouldn’t include it. Let’s call the rest of the output `r` for *result*:

```
search p (m:ms) = if p m then p:r else r
  where r = (??)
```

Now all we need to do is figure out what the rest of the result is. We know `r` must be of type `[Movie]` and if we think about it, `r` should be the list of movies from `ms` which satisfy the predicate `p`. I don’t have a great explanation for how to think of this but the best advice I can give is that by reading and writing lots of little recursive functions like this, one develops an intuition as to how to figure these out:

```
search p (m:ms) = if p m then p:r else r
  where r = search p ms
```

An alternative solution would be to use the `filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]` function from prelude:

```
search = filter
```